# SVN path-based authentication problem

Tags: svn

I am using an authz file to restrict access to a subversion server (svnserve). I would like to grant a user read-write access to a specific project in a repository, but no access to other projects in the same repository. My authz file looks like this:

```
[groups]
trusted = userA,userB,userC

[/]
@trusted = rw
* =

[repo1:/project1]
userD = rw
```

However with this authz file, userD can only *read*, but not *write* to /project1.

If I add the following:

```
[repo1:/]
userD = r
```

Then userD can both read and write to /project1.

This does not make any sense to me. According to the [subversion book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html), "the most specific path always matches first", so there should be no need for this. Furthermore, I can't understand that setting *read* permission is what actually lets this user *write* to the project.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I'm stumped, it looks fine to me.  What version of SVN are you using, client and server?  Also, how are you accessing the repo (eclipse, command line, etc)?

Comment: just tested this with mod_dav_svn 1.6.13 and it worked fine but having similar problems with svnserve

Comment: @John: svn server is 1.3.1. Accessing the repo from command line, but can't check the client version right now (different machine). I'll post it later today.

Comment: @vinnyjames: Interesting, that seems to point to a svnserve bug

Comment: @Grodriguez do you have an apache install you can test the config on with the mod_dav_svn?  I agree, if @vinnyjames is having the same issue then it is probably an svnserve bug.

Comment: @John no Apache on this machine, sorry :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a similar or the same bug as mentioned [here](http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=2712) in versions below 1.5.  I would highly recommend upgrading your repositories and SVN version to 1.6.  That can be kind of a pain though, as you'd have to dump and load the entire repo.  There's a good guide on migrating your repository [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch05s03.html#svn-ch-5-sect-3.5).  If your repo is small, it's not too long of a process (I've done it in a corporate environment).

An alternative would be to use apache as your SVN server host.

**EDIT:**

After scouring through the SVN changelogs, I found this in [1.4.3 Changes](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/tags/1.4.3/CHANGES):

> fixed: authz requires read access for
>   root for writes (issue #2486)

This sounds like your issue.  So supposedly it should be fixed after version 1.4.3.

Comment: Thanks John. I'm not sure it's really the same bug as I have anon-access set to none, which seems to fix all the issues mentioned there. I'll happily upgrade the repository but I would first like to know if this has really been fixed in a later version...